# Mapping an array inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to map an array of data, but keep getting the error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined for this line: `{number.s[0].l['serial'].map(option =>` 
This is my code:

```
{this.state.serials.map((number) => {
    return number.s && number.s.length? 
    (
        <h2 > {number.s[0].za}</h2>
        <ul>
        {number.s[0].l['serial'].map(option => 
          <li>{option}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    ) : null
})}
```

This is my data:

```
[
   {
     "s": [
            {
              "l": [
                     { "serial":"49:42:06:00:20:4e" }, 
                     { "serial":"49:42:06:00:3b:29" }
                   ],
              "za":"900"
            }
          ]
   },
   {
     "s": [
            {
              "l": [{ "serial":"777" }],
              "za":"5559"
            }
          ]
   }
]
```

Does anyone know how I should define the path to map serials from "l"? I defined it in many different ways, however, I can't seem to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ```l``` is an array. ```number.s[0].l.map(option => <li>{option.serial}</li>)```

Comment: @AshwynHorton Thanks! It works. If you want you could post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Great, I posted below. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l` is an array type. A simple fix here.

```
number.s[0].l.map(option => <li>{option.serial}</li>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should map `number.s[0].l.map((item)`.

Below is the complete `render` function

```js
render() {
        return(
            this.state.serials.map((number)=>{

                return ( number.s[0].za &&
                    <div>
                        <h2>{number.s[0].za}</h2>
                        {number.s[0].l && number.s[0].l.length > 0 &&
                        <ul>
                            {number.s[0].l && number.s[0].l.length>0 &&
                            number.s[0].l.map((item)=>{return   <li>{item.serial}</li>})
                            }
                        </ul>

                        }
                </div>
             )
            })
        )

    }
```